# How to select points in the same area for multiple pcd files?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

What I am trying to do is to select points in an area using PCL visualization tools. However, if I am processing multiple pcd files, I have to manually select the area using visualization tools for each files, which means I may not be able to select the same area for all of the files.
Is it possible to get the area we selected using PCL visualization tools since pcl::visualization::MouseEvent only gives me the point indices that I've selected.
Thank you!

Comment: So, tell me whether I understand it correctly or not. You select a region which include some indices, and in the next file you again want to select the same region, like a bounding box?

Comment: @NehilDanış  Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

Once you selected the pointcloud region in your visualization tool, you say that you can reach the indices. You can create a point cloud out of it, using the [extract indices](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/extract_indices.html) Once you have your cloud in the mouse click function, you can use pcl::getMinMax3D to get the max and min coordinates in all dimensions.

Once you have the max, min coordinate information of the area you cropped, for the next point cloud file, you can just use [PassThrough filter](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.html) to crop exact same area you selected using the mouse clicking event in the first point cloud file.